# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 over a windows partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I've looked around and couldn't find an answer to my problem so here it is. 
I have win 7 installed on a 500Gb drive. On it I have a small loader partition, 80 GB partition of windows 7 OS and 400 GB partition of data.
I want to wipe all windows  but keep my 400 GB data. In 16.04 installation I chose something else and I could locate my 80Gb windows partition but when choosing change I cannot resize it and create the swap and OS partitions I need per articles I found.
What should I do? also, what loader drive should I choose? in the drop down below the partition table.

Comment: You could delete that 80GB partition, and then create new partitions out of the unallocated space.

Comment: Can I delete it from the live CD? from the partition menu (while installing) or from the file manager?

Comment: Yes, exactly from the livecd, the Something Else section.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4GB of RAM or more, you don't really need a swap partition, unless you're running something memory hungry...

you can delet the 80GB partition without harming your data, and create new partitions in it's place...

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that you have a backup of your data partition before proceeding.

OK! Disclaimer out of the way...

From your live session, run gparted... If gparted is not on your live install media, as long as you have an active network connection, you can run

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

In my experience, it is easier to work directly with gparted when grooming the volumes for install from inside the installation application. 
Once gparted opens, you will be able to see the disk and its partitions graphically. If you have only the one drive, the boot loader partition should be sda1. The 80GB partition should be sda2. And, your 400GB partition should be sda3.

Make sure the disk(s) are free to be modified by unmounting the volume.

You can then delete the 80GB (sda2) partition and re-create a couple of smaller partitions. Perhaps 75GB for the main file system (and, you should create small partition. say 5GB and format it as SWAP) then simply reformat the larger partition to ext4 (for your main file system) and format the new small partition as SWAP. 
Your other ntfs partition will not be touched.

Close gparted once these changes have been successfully applied - (click the check mark on the menu bar to apply changes) No changes are actually made until you "commit" them by clicking the check mark and accepting the warning that pops up.

Resume your install using "something else". You have basically done all of the work. Now, you just need to tell it A) where to put the file system (the new 75GB partition B) where to assign the mount point ( "/" since no other OSs are present... and C) where to install the boot-loader (sda1 would be my suggestion)

Once the partition map appears, you can double click on the partition you want to hold your Ubuntu file system. This will select it for install. 
On the window that pops up, you can simply select your mount point - Again, I suggest "/" since no other OSs are on the drive anyway...

OK...close out that window and select the the boot-loader partition that is already on your drive (probably sda1) from the drop down list at the bottom of the main window.

That partition should already be formatted as FAT-MSDOS or similar... There will be no other operating system on the disk anyway. And, if it is not, installation will take care of making it suitable for booting linux.

When you are sure everything is ready... click on continue. Installation will list what changes are to be made to the disk. If these don't look right. For example if changes are scheduled for your 400GB partition, back out and double check you settings. Otherwise, accept the changes and proceed.

I think that pretty much covers it.

ENJOY that Ubuntu sweetness!